# Characters showed differently on console with respect to Jupyter Lab

Tags: unicode, fonts, console, unicode-string

Download [this file](https://0x0.st/oPX2.txt).

Now open the console and read its content:

```py
fh = open("out2.txt", "r", encoding="utf8")
data = fh.read()
fh.close()
print(data)
```

This is what I see:

[image]

Now I open Jupyter-lab and type the exact same commands.

This is what I now see:

[image]

Why are the characters showed differently on console and on Jupyter Lab?

Comment: To me, it seems a problem of fonts. Probably a font is using Unicode code points for different characters (I would assume the latter, because Unicode do not have so much support of music characters). OTOH it can also be that you are using ESC-codes to change font, and depending on console type and configuration you may get different behaviour. What do you get if you open the file in a text editor?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi in GVIM and in VIM I see the same thing I see in the console. This text is extracted from a PDF file, and in Evince I see the character interpreted as "2" too, which I get to be the correct answer for that character

Comment: The character interpreted as "2"  is  `` (U+F63A, *Private Use*).  All the "digits" in your file are Unicode from  `` (U+E000,  *<Private Use, First>*) to  `` (U+F8FF,  *<Private Use, Last>*).

Comment: @JosefZ if the character is in the private area, how does the console knows it is a 2?

Comment: See @GiacomoCatenazzi's comment: it's a font  (and/or [Font Fallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/input/font-technology#font-fallback) or
[Font Linking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/input/font-technology#font-linking)). See https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/F63A/fontsupport.htm as well.

Comment: @JosefZ thanks for the last link, but none of the font in the fileformat.info displays F63A as a "2". I'm using Fedora Workstation 35 and GNOME Terminal. How do I find out which font is actually used to render that character?

Comment: Please check my [FontGlyphs.py](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69283357/3439404) script (it's for Windows, sorry - try fixing it for Fedora?). Changing `fontsdirs` location could suffice?