# Python rich encoding issue with with Windows command prompt

Tags: python, encoding, rich

I tried something simple like:

```
with console.status("Processing...", spinner='aesthetic') as status:
     console.print(" ✓")
```

The expected view should be like this (copied from Pycharms command line):
▰▰▰▰▰▱▱ Processing  ✓

When I run the same script in a windows command prompt, the encoding seems to be lost. I really would like to copy the result in here, but then it is display correct.
In my Windows command prompt this -> ▰ and this -> ✓ look like a boxed questionmark.

Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/how-to-use-unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419/python-unicode-and-the-windows-console) will help.

Comment: Those *boxed question marks* are missing character glyphs in your font (e.g. `Lucida Console` or `Consolas`): (Glyph 0 / the `.notdef` glyph), see also ['cmap' Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/recom#glyph-0-the-notdef-glyph). Check my answer [How to determine if a Glyph can be displayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69283357/3439404). Set another font for your `cmd` (e.g. `DejaVu Sans Mono` or `Cascadia Mono`), or run your script from `cmd` tab inside Window Terminal…