# Why is there no super or subscript "q" or "Q" characters defined in UTF-8?

Tags: utf-8

The header says it all. I just would like to be able to write,

[image]

inline but I am stuck with `eᵖᐟᵠ`. Is there any way at all to achieve this simple thing?

Comment: UTF-8 is just a byte encoding of Unicode. The real question is, why doesn't **Unicode** define superscript versions of `Q` and `q`? For that, see [Why is there no character for "superscript q" in Unicode?](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-there-no-character-for-superscript-q-in-Unicode)

Comment: In short: Unicode is not for formatting, and superscript is considered formatting. Use a different layer for formatting (e.g. LaTeX, HTML, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UTF8 is an encoding scheme, if you are asking about why they aren't in Unicode:

As @JosefZ said, there are superscript characters for Q; U+A7F4 and q; U+107A5, but not very many fonts support them, even workhorses like Cambria Math.

Some of the superscript characters are in the Unicode blocks Latin Extended C, Latin Extended D, and Latin Extended F. These don't have wide font support, especially Latin Extended F.
[BabelStone Roman](https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Fonts/Roman.html) supports these Latin Extended blocks, but does not support Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols (U+1D400 - U+1D7FF). [Julia Mono](https://juliamono.netlify.app/) is also really good for mathematical symbol support, but does not support the Latin Extended blocks.

There are still missing superscript characters in Unicode, and I don't see the issue being fixed, maybe ever. In 2021 Kirk Miller proposed the addition of superscript S and superscript X to Unicode at code points A7F0 and A7F1 ([L2/21-089](https://www.unicode.org/L2/L2021/21089-mod-capital-letters.pdf)). The Unicode people ([UTC #167](http://www.unicode.org/L2/L2021/21073-script-adhoc-rept.pdf)) "noted" it, without rejecting it, and recommended no further action stating:

> "The examples do not show the two modifier capital letters being used
> for phonetic transcription, but  instead for morphological analysis
> apparatus, tone reconstruction and historical analysis, for which
> arbitrary letters could be used. In our view, rich text (or font-based
> stylistic sets) would be appropriate, but not plain text."

That's the same as killing it.

So, meanwhile, there is no superscript S, X, or Z in Unicode. And there probably won't be. We might get a "flying pig" emoji  (U+1F416 + U+1F6EB) -that's valid Unicode- instead.

You can use ᐟ `(U+141F), Canadian Syllabics Final Acute` as a superscript slash symbol for division, also missing from Unicode, and ᙆ `(U+1646) Canadian Syllabics Carrier Z` makes a pretty good superscript capital Z, but S and X... well... depending on the font, ᵡ `(U+1D61) Modifier Letter Small Chi` can work for X.

There are a LOT of holes in subscript in Unicode, if you need subscript other than numerals and a few characters here or there, just use TeX.

Here are your superscripts. You will likely see some boxes here, you can copy and paste into an application with supporting fonts.

```
Superscript
⁰ ¹ ² ³ ⁴ ⁵ ⁶ ⁷ ⁸ ⁹ 
ᵃ ᵇ ᶜ ᵈ ᵉ ᶠ ᵍ ʰ ⁱ ʲ ᵏ ˡ ᵐ ⁿ ᵒ ᵖ  ʳ ˢ ᵗ ᵘ ᵛ ʷ ˣ ʸ ᶻ
ᴬ ᴮ ꟲ ᴰ ᴱ ꟳ ᴳ ᴴ ᴵ ᴶ ᴷ ᴸ ᴹ ᴺ ᴼ ᴾ ꟴ ᴿ   ᵀ ᵁ ⱽ ᵂ ᵡ  ᙆ
⁺ ⁻ ⁼ ⁽ ⁾ ᐟ
```

Answer (score 1):

There **are** superscript `q` and `Q` characters defined in *Unicode version 14* (column `CodePoint` contains Unicode (`U+hhhh`) and UTF-8 bytes; column `Description` contains surrogates in parentheses):

```
Char CodePoint                      Description
---- ---------                      -----------
   ꟴ {U+A7F4, 0xEA,0x9F,0xB4}       MODIFIER LETTER CAPITAL Q
   {U+107A5, 0xF0,0x90,0x9E,0xA5} MODIFIER LETTER SMALL Q (0xd801,0xdfa5)
```

Appear in [UnicodeData.txt](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt) as follows (the file was previously downloaded from there):

```
findstr "Q;Lm;" D:\Utils\CodePages\UnicodeData.txt
```

> ```
> A7F4;MODIFIER LETTER CAPITAL Q;Lm;0;L;<super> 0051;;;;N;;;;;
> 107A5;MODIFIER LETTER SMALL Q;Lm;0;L;<super> 0071;;;;N;;;;;
> ```

You need to find a font containing glyph for *Modifier Letter Small Q* (maybe `Last Resort` font family?) Try [my answer to another question *How to determine if a Glyph can be displayed?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69283357/3439404)