# Font for "math bold script" unicode charset

Tags: unicode, fonts

I wouldn't believe I have been stuck on this for one hour, but it seems the fonts for extended unicode characters are not easyly available as TTF / OTF for use on computers, especially with graphic software where unicode fallback doesn't work

especifically I looking for the so called Math bold script

somehting like :     (<- those are extended chars)

as in https://textfancy.com/font-converter/

as imagen at: https://snipboard.io/fNYd7w.jpg

(becouse I am not sure we all see the same glyphs)

Note: what I am looking for, is a standrd TTF font, which normal glyphs are equal to those extended glyphs, meaning that the A looks like the , B like , and so on. So I could use the font as normal font in every software.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine if a Glyph can be displayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69261202/how-to-determine-if-a-glyph-can-be-displayed)

Comment: No, I do not think so. I am not looking for a way to display(hide extended glyphs, but for a font which standard letters are like those from the Math bold extended glyphs. Does it make sense ?

Comment: This doesn't really sound like a question that's on topic for this site.

Answer (score 1):

The STIX math fonts support the Unicode Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols block.

https://www.stixfonts.org/
https://github.com/stipub/stixfonts

(Note: the variable fonts don't include support for that block of characters; only the static fonts do.)

Please note the intended use of those Unicode characters, as pointed out in the STIX project:

> The sans serif, fraktur, script, etc., alphabets in Plane 1 (U+1D400-U+1D4FF) are intended to be used only as technical symbols.