# python reportlab - how to test whether a particular font (core or TTF) can encode/render a given glyph in a PDF?

Tags: python, reportlab

I've seen [How to determine if a Glyph can be displayed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69261202/how-to-determine-if-a-glyph-can-be-displayed), which doesn't seem to work for the core fonts.

https://docs.reportlab.com/reportlab/userguide/ch3_fonts/ talks about `reportlab.rl_config.warnOnMissingFontGlyphs`, but that seems to simply print a warning, which I don't see how to trap.

I'd be grateful for any insight.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work for me:

```
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont
import unicodedata

# font_name = 'Times-Roman'
font_name = '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSansMono-Thin.ttf'
# char_to_test = 'и'
char_to_test = 'A'

def font_can_render_glyph(font, glyph):
    name = unicodedata.name(glyph, "")
    if glyph in font.face.glyphWidths or name in font.face.glyphWidths:
        return True
    elif hasattr(font.face, 'charToGlyph') and ord(glyph) in font.face.charToGlyph:
        return True
    return False

if font_name[-4:] == ".ttf":
    font = TTFont(font_name, font_name)
else:
    font = pdfmetrics.getFont(font_name)

if font_can_render_glyph(font, char_to_test):
    print(f"The font '{font.fontName}' can render the glyph '{char_to_test}'.")
else:
    print(f"The font '{font.fontName}' cannot render the glyph '{char_to_test}'.")
```